# Git rebase automatically removing files from branch

Tags: git, command-line-interface, git-rebase

I'm working on a branch of master that I'm trying to update with the latest master.

Unfortunately when I rebase it raising 1 conflict - no problem, I resolve that and run `git rebase --continue` it then announces it is removing 4 files (that are new to my branch, are committed and push to the remote branch)

```
$ git rebase --continue
Applying: holding commit
Applying: partial migration of candidate search to primary repo
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       .eslintrc
M       .gitignore
M       package.json
M       src/app.tsx
.git/rebase-apply/patch:2854: trailing whitespace.
            
warning: 1 line adds whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Removing src/candidate/components/row-company.tsx
Removing src/candidate/components/row-candidate.tsx
Removing src/candidate/components/col-company.tsx
Removing src/candidate/components/col-candidate.tsx
Auto-merging src/app.tsx
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/app.tsx
Auto-merging package.json
Auto-merging .eslintrc
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in .eslintrc
error: Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0002 partial migration of candidate search to primary repo
hint: Use 'git am --show-current-patch' to see the failed patch
Resolve all conflicts manually, mark them as resolved with
"git add/rm <conflicted_files>", then run "git rebase --continue".
```

All 4 files have not previously been in master and have been updated on the branch more recently than master.

I'm rebasing by:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout <branch>
git rebase master
```

I cannot see a reason for git removing these files so all suggestions welcome.

Comment: Without more information, *we* can't see the reason either. We'd need access to your repository.

Comment: unfortunately that's not via as is a client project and cannot be made public - what further information I can provide? (other than access)

Comment: Well, running  `git fetch` followed by `git log --all --decorate --graph --oneline` will give us *some* information (save the output with a logger somewhere, e.g., on Linux use `script` to save it to a file). You could then cut-and-paste the output, or some subset of it, into your question. That might still be more than you want to give out though.